# How to access text in all instances of a certainclass with a span inside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rate box on my site that appears beneath an article, and then again that same rate box appears on comments people leave regarding the article. So the rate box appears multiple times on the page. I'm trying to change the text that appears within that rate box, but infortunately I don't have server access on the type of site I have. So I need to do it with scripting.

The small script I'm using now works, but it's only working for the very first rate box. I need to change the text in each of them however. I'm trying to change the existing text that says "Rate" into "Like".

`.SUI-RateBox` is the div class, and the text I need to change sits in a span within that class.

The code that I have that works on just the first instance is this:

```
<script>
  $(".SUI-RateBox span:contains('Rate')").html("Like");
</script>
```

How can I make this happen, but to all of the rate boxes.
The dom structure is at the below link.

http://www.spruzstuff.spruz.com/pt/Element-Background-Image/wiki.htm

Comment: If your structure of elements is a predictable pattern, then don't use `:contains`. That's a last resort selector at best. If you're going to ask about DOM selection, then you really need to show what the DOM looks like.

Comment: @user1689607 I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using `#` (nevermind, you changed your question's details), but try this:

```
<script>
   $(".SUI-RateBox").find("span:contains('Rate')").html("Like");
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EhPP7/

Comment: Lol, it was a typo. I was trying to test what I was doing with the .css just to make sure I was accessing things properly. I pasted the wrong code.. Sorry :)

Comment: How would this behave differently from the original?

Comment: That still only works on the very first rate box it seems. But it doesn't appear to be problem within the script. I'm overlooking something in the html. False alarm, and thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps someone can tell me what I'm missing in the html? The page example is here http://www.spruzstuff.spruz.com/pt/How-to-create-a-Javascript-Popup-BoxAlert-Box-for-your-Spruz-site.10-2-2012/wiki.htm

Comment: @user1689607 So, originally the question had different code. But I thought I'd keep it here to prove that it at least does work on test HTML. And not that it matters, but I like separating things as much as possible (instead of one big selector), and I found out it is actually faster (as miniscule as it is).

Comment: @RandyCramer Unrelated - have you looked at your browser's error log? I see a `setInterval` running that throws an error because `x is undefined`.

Comment: @RandyCramer Yep, and I lied, the error message is: `TypeError: x is null.......document.title = title + x.innerText;`

Comment: @ianpgall Yeah, I keep forgetting to update that. innerText doesn't have firefox support I believe. Thanks

Comment: @RandyCramer Ah yeah, that's true. Any reason `innerHTML` is a bad idea? Does it contain HTML or just text?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I guess you could also try `.each()` to iterate through each of span tags within `div.SUI-RateBox` and check text value one after another.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*.SUI-RateBox").each(function(){
        var sp = $(this).children("span");
        if(sp.text() == 'Rate')
            sp.text('like');            
    });
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cZMFC/1/

Also check out [jQuery .each() API](http://api.jquery.com/each/)